QPolarChart how do I make the outer circle invisible?
Here is an example of a QPolarChart with both radial and angular axis.

I want to remove radial axis (which I can do by not adding the radial axis), but I want the outer circle removed as well. I expect the end result to have only the angular axis like this:

Is that possible with QPolarChart?

This is the axes initialization for QPolarChart* chart:
chart->createDefaultAxes();
auto angular_axis = qobject_cast<QtCharts::QValueAxis*>(chart->axes().at(0));
auto radial_axis = qobject_cast<QtCharts::QValueAxis*>(chart->axes().at(1));

angular_axis->setLabelsVisible(false); // hiding the tick labels

// hiding the axis' "arrow" that is represented by the outer circle
angular_axis->setLineVisible(false);

radial_axis->setLabelsVisible(false); // hiding the tick labels
radial_axis->setGridLineVisible(false); // hiding the grid circles


Can you please provide more insight in your answer in order to clarify the reasoning and behavior behind it?

radial_axis->setGridLineVisible(false);
This removes only the inner circles, but the outer circle still exists

@AlanZ. It works fine with Qt 5.12. I also set the color to background by setGridLineColor. The same result.

@StasSimonov you're right, it worked. Thanks boss!
